# How to write a custom mail adapter in phabricator?

Tags: php, email, phabricator

I'm trying to write a custom mail adapter in **phabricator**. I wrote my own class A in this path **phabricator>src>applications>metamta>adapter>A.php**.

I made sure this extends PhabricatorMailImplementationAdapter and set this in my set metamta.mail-adapter .

However on building I get the following error

```
Usage Exception: Option 'metamta.mail-adapter' value must name a class extending 'PhabricatorMailImplementationAdapter'.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This worked for me yesterday, but today it throws 'E XCEPTION: (Exception) xhpast is broken. at [<phutil>/src/parser/xhpast/bin/PhutilXHPASTBinary.php:47]                                                                                                                                                                     
phutil()  '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `arc liberate` to build a new library map, so your new class can be found by Phabricator.

Comment: Yes thankyou.. I found this later in the evening as well... I ran ./arcanist/bin/arc liberate phabricator/ and it worked