# Arc liberate error in phabricator

Tags: php, phabricator, arcanist

This is a follow up to [my previous phabricator question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550951/how-to-write-a-custom-mail-adapter-in-phabricator)

On running arc liberate in phabricator I'm running into  the following error

> arcanist/bin/arc liberate phabricator/
>   [2015-07-23 22:34:05] EXCEPTION: (Exception) xhpast is broken. at [/src/parser/xhpast/bin/PhutilXHPASTBinary.php:47]
>   phutil()
>     #0 PhutilXHPASTBinary::build() called at [/src/moduleutils/PhutilLibraryMapBuilder.php:446]
>     #1 PhutilLibraryMapBuilder::analyzeLibrary() called at [/src/moduleutils/PhutilLibraryMapBuilder.php:77]
>     #2 PhutilLibraryMapBuilder::buildMap() called at [/src/moduleutils/PhutilLibraryMapBuilder.php:109]
>     #3 PhutilLibraryMapBuilder::buildAndWriteMap() called at [/scripts/phutil_rebuild_map.php:75]               `

I looked online and could not find guidance to my specific problem. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

it should just be:

```
cd /path/to/phabricator/
arc liberate
```

If xphast is actually your problem, you can just rebuilt it in libphutil.
https://github.com/phacility/libphutil/blob/master/scripts/build_xhpast.php